# Patternmatching in custom types

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

Consider the following types:

```
data MyType = MyType Val Col deriving (Eq, Show)
data Val = Val A | B | C deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
data Col = X | Y | Z deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read)
```

If I now have a function like `sameVal :: MyType -> MyType -> Bool` that is supposed to check the `Val` field for equality and try to do it like this:

```
sameVal (MyType v _) (MyType v _) = True
sameVal _ _ = False
```

GHC whines at me telling me that `v` has conflicting definitions...

```
Conflicting definitions for ‘v’
Bound at: htest.hs:6:14
          htest.hs:6:24
In an equation for ‘sameVal’
```

but its supposed to imply that they have to be the same. What am I not getting here?

Note: I get that I could just give them different names and compare `v1` and `v2` later in the function body. This question is about pattern-matching in general, not this specific example.

Tank's for any Help.

Comment: sorry did not see... these answer my question... (cant delete now because of answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but its supposed to imply that they have to be the same. What am I not getting here?

Just that Haskell doesn't allow this. Some languages with pattern matching do (e.g. Erlang), others don't (Haskell, OCaml, Scala).